# RSA Cryptography math problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I have this math problem I'm kind of stuck on.

> You intercept the message 27284682555982882069237 which was encrypted
>    using a public modulus of 124137798108168664109413 and an encryption
>    exponent 257. The modulus is now too large to be factored by testing
>    successive candidate divisors (although it can be done using more
>    sophisticated algorithms). However Bob, who is the intended recipient
>    of the message, runs several online businesses. and the public key
>    information for his other business is modulus 283967477199546905990801
>    and encryption exponent 257.
>
> You have heard a rumor that Bob has a ‘lucky prime’, which he uses as
>    one of the prime factors for all the moduli he generates. Verify that
>    this rumor is true (how do you check if the two moduli have a common
>    prime factor?) and then use this information to decrypt the message.

I know that this is an RSA problem... so I believe that $p = 124137798108168664109413$ and $e = 257$, if that's correct... However, I'm sot sure how to continue. Thanks.

Comment: You should look for the GCD of the two moduli, shouldn't you?  Wouldn't that be the lucky prime in question?

Comment: @BrianTung Alright, so I got gcd(124137798108168664109413, 283967477199546905990801) = 556864830521... How do I decrypt the message?

Answer (score 0):

Call the moduli $m_1$ and $m_2$, to avoid my having to refer to those big long numbers.  The rumor that Bob uses a "lucky prime" $p$ is equivalent to the claim that there exist two other primes $q_1, q_2$ such that $m_1 = pq_1$ and $m_2 = pq_2$.

In that case, the totient values of the two moduli are

$$
\phi(m_1) = (p-1)(q_1-1)
$$
$$
\phi(m_2) = (p-1)(q_2-1)
$$

We know that for both keys, the encryption exponent is $e = 257$.  So then the decryption exponents $d_1, d_2$ are characterized by

$$
ed_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(m_1)}
$$
$$
ed_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(m_2)}
$$

Hopefully, you can take it from here.

Comment: So, I'm left with $$257d_1\equiv 1\pmod{(556864830520)(q_1-1)}$$$$257d_2\equiv 1\pmod{(556864830520)(q_2-1)}$$right?

Comment: Well, you can find out what $q_1 = m_1/p$ and $q_2 = m_2/p$ are first, yes?  You know the two moduli and the lucky prime now.

Comment: So$$257d_1\equiv 1\pmod{(556864830520)(222922675852)}$$$$257d_2\equiv 1\pmod{(556864830520)(509939686680)}$$right?

Comment: I haven't the wherewithal at the moment to confirm your arithmetic, but the form of the equations are correct.

Comment: So how would I find $d_1$ and $d_2$? Would I have to multiply those 2 large numbers together?

Comment: How do you normally find $d$ when you do RSA?  Have you done an RSA key generation problem yet?  If not, you should practice that first.  This problem uses that skill...

Comment: Look here for some tips: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: How would I decrypt it with $d_1$ and $d_2$?

Comment: You really need to do some more background reading on RSA.  You decrypt by raising the ciphertext to the power of $d$ modulo $m$.

Comment: I usually do it with one equation not 2 though

Comment: You only have one equation.  One of them was only to furnish you another modulus for determining the lucky prime!

Comment: $$257d_1\equiv 1\pmod{(556864830520)(222922675852)}$$$$257d_2\equiv 1\pmod{(556864830520)(509939686680)}$$That's 2 equations, no?

Comment: The second equation has nothing to do with the message!

Comment: So, would I have to use Euclid's Algorithm to solve this?

Comment: So, I got $d = 42023301304835923208033$

Comment: So, I got this as my decrypted message... 82723797137527196465877